# who and whom on django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to figure out how people will write comments and how to store for whom it is written and who wrote. I'd like to see the Comments written for a person UserProfile.Comments...

Anyone can help me about it?

*MODELS.PY*

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    comments =  models.ForeignKey("Comments", null=True, blank=True)


class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    who_wrote = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

VIEW.PY (here i stuck)

```
def writecomment(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.user_id = get_object_or_404(User, username=username).id
            #frm = form.save()

            usr = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user = request.user)
            usr.Comments = form #append??
            usr.save()

   else:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) 

    return render_to_response("writecomment.html", {"form": form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your models could be created a little differently to make this task easier.  Just some things to think about.

1. Can each user have multiple comments? `UserProfile` has a field called `comments` suggesting that it could be.  This might be better modeled as a many to many field.
2. Should `UserProfile` link to a user?
3. It seems like `Comments` might need to support 2 users, a from user and a to user.

---

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User) # each user can have exactly 1 profile
     comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment) # each user can have mutilple comments


class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    to = # shoudl this be foreign key or many to many?
    # can a comment reference multiple users or just one user or no user?
```

With changes above, getting the comments to a user or from a user becomes a lot easier

Comment: Yes, a user can have multiple comments from different people. 
UserProfile is already linked with the User with OneToOne Field and Signal.

"to" should be ManyToMany
I am checking the code in the way you offered.
And yes, Comments might need to support 2 users, a from user and a to user.